# Linebreak using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

So, I have a bunch of array data that I want to write in HTML, but for some of them I need to insert line breaks instead of showing them as mere paragraphs. The following is an example.

```
        let welcome= document.createElement("div")
        welcome.setAttribute('id', 'welcome')
        welcome.className = 'w3-container w3-center w3-animate-opacity'
        let welcomeTextNode = document.createTextNode(`Hi, using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject.`)        
        welcome.appendChild(welcomeTextNode)
        document.body.appendChild(welcome)
```

The output on the page is supposed to be like this

```
Hi,
using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject.
```

I've tried adding '\n', but even though in the html code it adds the line break, it still shows it as a single line on the page. I've tried inserting '< br >' in the string hoping it would see it as tag but it sees it as part of the string and shows like this.

```
Hi, <br> using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject.
```

I've tried creating a br element and inserted it as variable in the string

```
let br = document.createElement('br')
```

but it shows like this

```
Hi, [object HTMLBRELEMENT] using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject.
```

I'm out of options.

I'm sure it's possible to modify the texts shown on the page usign javaascript but I don't know how to do that.

Looking for kind answers.

Comment: What about `welcome.innerHTML = 'Hi, <br> using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject.'`?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `innerHTML` to do this

```js
        let welcome= document.createElement("div");
        welcome.setAttribute('id', 'welcome');
        welcome.className = 'w3-container w3-center w3-animate-opacity'
        welcome.innerHTML = "Hi, <br> using the side bar, you can find the 
        information regarding your subject";
        document.body.appendChild(welcome);
```

with `innerHTML`, you can put html elements like `<br>` inside strings

output :

```
hi, 
using the side bar, you can find the information regarding your subject"
```